# Raspberry pi touch display

Tags: raspbian, display, touchscreen

Im using rasberry pi 3 , and im having XPT2046 Touch Controller which is a 3.5 inch RPi display , i need to connect the display to the rasberry pi , ive tried several methods like frimware update ,but after that im just getting the black screen, so i reinstalled the os again , anybody know any site with working tutorial for connecting XPT2046 with rasberry pi .Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site seems to have a [tutorial and most importantly drivers](http://ozzmaker.com/piscreen-driver-install-instructions-2/) for this type of 3.5 touch screen.  Hope it helps.